# training datasets for object detection

Tags: opencv, dataset, object-detection, training-data

I have a short question about preparing training datasets. Is it possible to find already training datasets for vehicles, pedestrians, and traffic signs? It is very time consuming to crop (mark) every image by hand and it takes days to train.

Answer (score 4):

- For vehicles, you can use [**HRI RoadTraffic dataset**](http://www.gepperth.net/alexander/interests.html#carbenchmark), which is a large-scale vehicle detection dataset.
- For pedestrian, the most famous one is [**INRIA Person Dataset**](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/).
- For traffic signs, you can use [**Urban scene recognition dataset**](http://www.lara.prd.fr/benchmarks/trafficlightsrecognition).

---

In case that you may need other datasets, you can check out [CV Datasets on the web](http://www.cvpapers.com/datasets.html) for more info.